# How can I pass ngForm object to my custom directive?

Tags: angular4-forms

I have an Input box inside a form object with NgForm directive.
I have created a custom directive separately.
Just want to pass the NgForm object to my custom directive.

My html:

```html
<form name="myForm" #myForm="ngForm" custValidate novalidate>
  <input type="text" name="email" custValidate="emailValidate" class="form-control" ngModel required>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" custValidate="nameValidate" class="form-control" ngModel required>
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

The console is coming as string only. I want it to be the NgForm object.

Its a requirement so cannot add ngSubmit function in the compponent as shown in the official docs (https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm);

Comment: could you please add the directives code aswell?

Comment: Directive :

export class MyCustomDirective {

  @Input('td-validate') type: any;
  @Input() formType: any;

@HostListener('submit')
  formSubmit() {
    console.log(typeof(this.formType));
  }
}